# Different Metastore/Data Catalog options with Apache Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, hive-metastore

What are the metastore/data-catalog options I can use with Apache Spark?

In the simples case, I can use the Hive Metastore - which works great with Hive, Spark and Presto.
Are there any other data catalog options I can use here?

Comment: Answer not good enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unashamedly from the documentation to be found at https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-hive-tables.html:

> Spark SQL also supports reading and writing data stored in Apache
>   Hive. However, since Hive has a large number of dependencies, these
>   dependencies are not included in the default Spark distribution. If
>   Hive dependencies can be found on the classpath, Spark will load them
>   automatically. Note that these Hive dependencies must also be present
>   on all of the worker nodes, as they will need access to the Hive
>   serialization and deserialization libraries (SerDes) in order to
>   access data stored in Hive.
>
> Configuration of Hive is done by placing your hive-site.xml,
>   core-site.xml (for security configuration), and hdfs-site.xml (for
>   HDFS configuration) file in conf/.
>
> When working with Hive, one must instantiate SparkSession with Hive
>   support, including connectivity to a persistent Hive metastore,
>   support for Hive serdes, and Hive user-defined functions. Users who do
>   not have an existing Hive deployment can still enable Hive support.
>   When not configured by the hive-site.xml, the context automatically
>   creates metastore_db in the current directory and creates a directory
>   configured by spark.sql.warehouse.dir, which defaults to the directory
>   spark-warehouse in the current directory that the Spark application is
>   started. Note that the hive.metastore.warehouse.dir property in
>   hive-site.xml is deprecated since Spark 2.0.0. Instead, use
>   spark.sql.warehouse.dir to specify the default location of database in
>   warehouse. You may need to grant write privilege to the user who
>   starts the Spark application.

But may be you mean something else? Simple cases?